# Java Command Line Argument Program

Tags: java, methods, command-line-arguments, charat

My program requires input from command line arguments, it takes the integer argument and converts it to either its binary value or its decimal base 10 value. It makes this decision by requiring the integer to have a b in front of the number for binary and a d in front for a decimal base 10. This program requires me to complete this by creating methods. I don't know how to first check the character then to get the remaining numbers. I know the toBinary method but I don't know how to do the binary to decimal conversion?

Answer (score 2):

use 
s.charAt(0) to get check first character and use

String s1 = s.substring(1, s.length);

to get remaining string number and use it to convert it to integer user Integer.parse(s1); based on first character.

use following to convert binary to integer: Integer.parseInt(s1,2)

Comment: if you complete this for me in 30min ill etransfer you $10